# JavaScript join Array objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
array = [
  {name:'alfa', firstValue:{value:'100'}},
  {name:'alfa', secoundValue:{value:'200'}},
  {name:'alfa', thirdValue:{value:'300'}}
]
```

I'm looking for a way to copy objects props into unique when the value name are the same, how can I do this, see expected result below:

```
array = [
  {name:'alfa', firstValue:{value:'100'}, secoundValue:{value:'200'}, thirdValue:{value:'300'}},
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
array = [
  {name:'alfa', firstValue:{value:'100'}},
  {name:'alfa', secoundValue:{value:'200'}},
  {name:'alfa', thirdValue:{value:'300'}}
]

const result = array.reduce((a, b) => {
  let found = a.find(e => e.name == b.name);
  found ? Object.assign(found, b) : a.push(b);
  return a;
}, [])

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks I was looking for exactly reducer + object assign, works great!

Comment: The main downside here is `O(n^2)` performance; besides that it's a fine solution